# What does ArcGIS have that QGIS doesn't?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.10 and I'm comfortable with this linux OS. I installed latest QGIS and it works just fine and something that I'm curious and keen to get answers from you is, what can possibly be in ArcGIS that there is no way I can have it in QGIS? i.e Map layers available?

Comment: QGIS does not support sending you large invoices every year.

Comment: It's a great question but not as clear a comparison as you may think.  You are not ESRI's target market, large, enterprise-level organizations are.  This is very clear if you look at their software suite as a whole, and read their newsletter.

Comment: Spacedman way ahead . . .

Comment: Top notch banter @Spacedman

Comment: The ArcGIS licensing system is a thing of enormous beauty -- it makes installing Windows seem almost trivial. Seriously, if you like using Linux and QGIS meets your needs, then this question it too broad for a useful answer.

Answer (score 8):

ArcGIS has certain benefits and advantages if you are running an organization, or if you're part of a local government, through its Enterprise applications (ArcCollector for iPad, for example). However, it is proprietary and costs a lot of money. If you're an individual GIS/Mapmaker, QGIS is the way to go.

QGIS is free and covers most of what ArcGIS can do through various plugin contributors. Need to do something in QGIS that isn't part of the standard interface? There's probably a plugin for it.

QGIS can also be finnicky at times (certain plugins not working, or not working as well as you might like), and new versions come out far more frequently than versions of ArcGIS, meaning staying up to date on your versions. I don't mind that, personally. It's enjoyable to be a part of an Open Source community, while at the same time, being able to accomplish pretty much any GIS or Remote Sensing need I have.

Also, to be more specific to your question, Land Cover Classification tools in ArcGIS are much more sophisticated than they are in QGIS. If I had to work with satellite imagery in ArcGIS or QGIS, it would definitely be the former. ArcGIS also allows Time-Series mapping, which, as far as I know, isn't available in QGIS.

Comment: for timeseries see http://anitagraser.com/2011/04/10/an-introduction-to-time-manager-for-qgis/

Comment: Thank you @kadenz for your response. It is helpful and I am glad to know about "Land Cover Classification" - will have to know more about how it works in Arc.

Mh! have you used openlayer plugin in QGIS, can't it achieve the same output?

Comment: regarding your first point, it really depends what the staff in large organisations/local governments actually do in GIS. You could have 50 light GIS users who just want to load, view and edit the odd shapefile here and there. QGIS would be a sensible roll out in that scenario. Or you could have an entire division of heavy GIS users running complex analyses under a limitless budget. A mass install of ArcGIS Pro could be a slick solution there.

Answer (score 7):

[GIS Geography](http://gisgeography.com/) has a great article on **[27 Differences Between ArcGIS and QGIS – The Most Epic GIS Software Battle in GIS History](http://gisgeography.com/qgis-arcgis-differences/)**

[image]

Comment: Just to add, a new version of this article comparing ArcGIS Pro and QGIS 3 was written earlier in 2021: https://gisgeography.com/arcgis-pro-vs-qgis-3/

Answer (score 7):

The biggest issue you face is having chosen Linux is that ArcMap doesn't come in a linux version so you need to build a Windows VM just to run your GIS. QGIS runs everywhere (mostly).

This [blog post](https://gisunchained.wordpress.com/2016/01/28/qgis-features-i-long-for-while-using-arcgis/), **QGIS Features I long for while using ArcGIS
(aka Features that ArcGIS Desktop users might not know that exists)**, is an interesting discussion of things that Arc users might not know about.

Comment: Thanks! the blog have help me to get better understanding about this two software and where the actual difference is at...!